# Generated table with rowspan causing extra cells

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, html

**HTML**

```
<table id="tableAppointment" bgcolor="#fcfcfc" border="1" cellspacing="1" width="100%">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <td class="csstextheader" width="70px"></td>
   <td class="csstextheader" width="70px"><b>Time Slot&nbsp;</b></td>
   <td><b>Room 7</b></td>
   <td><b>Room 8</b></td>
   <td><b>Room 9</b></td>
   <td><b>Room 10</b></td>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr class="csstablelisttd">
   <td width="70px">08:00AM</td>
   <td>00</td>
   <td class="csstdred">John</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

**C#**

```
private void GenerateTable() {
    for(int i = 0; i < tableAppointment.Rows.Count; i++) {
        foreach(DataRow dr in dataTableAcqModality.Rows) {
            cell = new HtmlTableCell() {
                InnerHtml = "&nbsp;"
            };
            cell.Style.Add("word-wrap", "break-word");
            cell.Attributes.Remove("class");
            cell.Attributes.Remove("rowspan");
            cell.Style.Remove("display");

            tableAppointment.Rows[i].Cells.Add(cell);
            tableAppointment.Style.Add("table-layout", "fixed");

            if(i == 0) {
                cell.Attributes.Add("ID", RoomID.ToString());
                cell.InnerHtml = String.Format(
                    "<span id='{0}'>{1}</span>",
                    RoomID, Roomname
                );
                tableAppointment.Rows[0].Attributes.Add("class", "csstextheader");
            }
        }
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    for(int i = 0; i < tableAppointment.Rows.Count; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < tableAppointment.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++) {
            // This is where I need to remove the extra cells added 
            // after providing rowspan :(
        }
    }
}
```

In [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/eguguk/1/edit), you can see the extra cells which get stuck on the right side of my rows due to `rowspan` being added to cells in the rows above. I'm trying to figure out how to remove these. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: You should really indent your html code properly. Right now I don't think anyone is going to read it. Same applies to the C# code below. While that's readable because it's very short proper indentation is still a good thing.

Comment: Can you explain exactly which cell you want to remove? Can't uderstand the criteria

Comment: see in jsbin i have extra cell added so thts cells have to remove it..

Comment: Looking at the jsbin, are you wanting to remove the final two columns of cells?

Comment: How you generate your table? I think it's better not to add those extra cells, then try to remove them after creation. Also, your table is not server control, how going access it in code behind?

Comment: Show us how you generate your table? Then we might be able to help you not generate those extra cells altogether, then you don't have to remove them.

Comment: see in quetion i have add code for generating table dynamically..

Comment: tableAppointment.Rows[row + 1].Cells[col].RowSpan = 3;

Comment: like above i m giving rowspan to cell depend on time slot where each time slot is 15 minutes'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though I don't know what you want, or have any idea why, [I wrote some jQuery](http://jsbin.com/eguguk/2/) to remove the extra columns, because that's what we do here on StackOverflow.

*I make no guarantees as to the efficiency or actual usefulness of this code.*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('table tr').each(function(i, v) {
    var cols = $(this).find('td');
    $(this).find('td[rowspan]').each(function() {
      var idx = $(this).index();
      console.log(idx);
      for(var j = 1; j < $(this).prop('rowspan'); j++) {
        $('table tr').eq(i+j).find('td').eq(idx).hide();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Edit: Apparently you just need to give the rows a height to avoid that collapsing into each other behavior:

```
tr { height: 30px; }
```

Edit 2: I did update my jQuery to hide the cells immediately below a cell with a rowspan.  It looks like you have conflicting appointments in your example. Joking aside, you probably want to deal with making sure there are no scheduling conflicts and not writing those extra cells in the first place.

A general strategy to deal with this ahead of time would be to initialize a multidimensional array of booleans (say `cellsUsed`) the same size as your table to false, then when printing a cell with having a rowspan, mark the rowspan - 1 array locations as true.  Then when it's time to write a cell which corresponds to an array index set to true, you just *don't* output anything. If there happens to be an actual appointment defined in a cell you marked not to output, you have an entirely different problem, and have to deal with that.

EDIT: Here's a demonstration of why you have to hide the extra cells or go over the table twice to remove them in order to avoid errors:

Here's an example table where 'a' is a cell having rowspan > 1.  an 'x' specifies the extra cells which need to be deleted, and a '-' signifies a blank which is intended to be blank.

This is the starting data in the table:

```
a-a-
x-xa
xaxx
-x-x
```

This is what happens if you start deleting from bottom left to top-right.  After you delete the extra cell connected to the appointment in the second-to-last row you only have three cells in the last row.  So when you traverse downward from the next appointment to delete fourth cell in that row, you get an error.

```
a-a-
x-xa
xaxx
--x!
```

If you try to delete from top-right to bottom left, when you go to delete the second appointment you end up erroneously deleting another appointment (The two 'a' stacked adjacently).

```
a-a-
-xa
axx
-x-x
```

The only way to avoid problems deleting the cells after generating the table is to mark all the cells you want deleted, then delete the cells in each row from right to left.

Comment: but it didnt see like block...see when we we give rowspan to cell it looks like a block...in my jsbin after giving rowspan cell looks like a block..when we give rowspan to cell its below row cell have to remove to see like a block...........

Comment: Here, this version has a hideous visual artifact instead.

Comment: In above jsbin u see persons appointment is fixed with respect to time and Room number where each time slot is 15 minutes if rowspan is 3 then person appointment time is 45 minutes if rowspan is 2 then person appointment time is 30 minutes and if rowspan is 1 then person appointment time is 15 minutes..So when i give rowspan then its under cells get added in table....This is my scenario..So how we remove that extra added cells..

Comment: @Nikhil I almost see what you're getting at.

Comment: @Nikhil I explained that. Ricky @ 1:45 Room 8 conflicts with Feder @ 1:15 Room 8. You can't really display overlapping table cells *properly*.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20298/discussion-between-mootinator-and-nikhil)

Comment: mootinator shall i considere is working solution because when i fixed apointment getting no error....or is there any problem....

Comment: I would expect output from an actual routine with no conflicts to look like this: http://jsbin.com/eguguk/4/ Like I said though, it would really be better to avoid printing the extra empty cells in the first place but you didn't provide the code you use to do that so it's difficult to suggest a change.

Answer (score 4):

To simplify it for you ..

If you use `[rowspan="2"]` in cell --> then you have to remove one cell from the next row

Example :

```
<table id="Table1" >
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" style="border-style:solid"></td>
        <td style="border-style:solid"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border-style:solid"></td>          
    </tr>
</table>
```

If you use [ rowspan="3" ] in cell --> then you have to remove one cell from the next **two** rows

Example :

```
<table id="Table1" >
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3" style="border-style:solid"></td>
        <td style="border-style:solid"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border-style:solid"></td>          
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border-style:solid"></td>          
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < tableAppointment.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < tableAppointment.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
        {
             // Assuming you have set the rowSpan by now.
             // TODO: Handle the possibility of missing rowspan attribute.
             int rowSpan = int.Parse(tableAppointment.Rows[i].Cells[j].Attributes["rowspan"]);
             if (rowSpan > 0) {
                // Now try to look ahead for rows and remove their j'th cell.
                for (int k = j+1; k < j + rowSpan; k++)
                {
                   tableAppointment.Rows[k].Cells.RemoveAt(j);
                   // TODO: Validate if k is not beyond available rows. It shoudn't be if rowspans are correct.
                }
             }
        }        //Here i have to remove those extra cell added after giving rowspan       
    }
}
```

**NOTE: This code has not been tested, or even compiled. Provided more as a guidance.**

Having said this I believe you can handle this better at the time of generating the table. If I understood correctly (may be I didn't) you have the table statically created, and then you inject the appointments. 
That is why you get this extra-cell syndrome. If you generate the entire table dynamically this should not happen to you.

Answer (score 1):

if your cells are blank then you can hide from css. like;

```
table{empty-cells:hide;}
```

Comment: That would hide most cells in his table.

Answer (score 1):

I had to make assumptions since there is code missing: getting the data, what the data looks like, how the appointments are added to the table.

There are two things that I did to fix the issue.
1 - I switched the order of the loops, instead of looping through each room for a time span, I looped through all the time spans for one room before moving on the the next room.
2 - Because of change #1, I was able to increment the time span counter by the number of cells that needed to be removed (not recommended)

Default.aspx.cs

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
  //Used to store generated data.
  List<Room> Rooms = new List<Room>();

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
      //To simulate the datasource
      GenerateData();

      //Generate the output
      GenerateTable();
    }
  }

  private void GenerateData()
  {
    //Generate Rooms
    foreach (var roomNumber in Enumerable.Range(7, 4))
    {
      var newRoom = new Room();

      newRoom.RoomID = roomNumber;
      newRoom.Roomname = "Room " + roomNumber.ToString();
      //Generate 40 15-minute time slot appointments for each room
      for (var count = 0; count < 40; ++count)
      {
        var newAppointment = new Appointment();

        newAppointment.Id = (roomNumber * 40) + count;
        newAppointment.Name = " ";
        newAppointment.NumberOfTimeSlots = 1;

        newRoom.Appointments.Add(newAppointment);
      }

      Rooms.Add(newRoom);
    }

    Rooms[0].Appointments[0].Name = "John";
    Rooms[0].Appointments[0].NumberOfTimeSlots = 1;

    Rooms[0].Appointments[2].Name = "John";
    Rooms[0].Appointments[2].NumberOfTimeSlots = 3;

    Rooms[1].Appointments[14].Name = "calc";
    Rooms[1].Appointments[14].NumberOfTimeSlots = 3;

    //More can be added
  }

  private void GenerateTable()
  {
    //Moved outside of the loop since it is globally setting the table and does not need to run for each row.
    tableAppointment.Style.Add("table-layout", "fixed");

    /**********************************************************************************************
     * Major change 1:
     * I flipped the order of the loops, I changed it from row->column to column->row.
     * What this allows you to do is skip the step of adding additional rows for the current room
     * by increment the row counter (not a good practice, need to refactor code).
     **********************************************************************************************/

    //You had: foreach(DataRow dr in dataTableAcqModality.Rows) {
    //I am assuming that this is a list of rooms to display
    foreach (var dr in Rooms)      
    {

      for (int i = 0; i < tableAppointment.Rows.Count; ++i)
      {
        var cell = new HtmlTableCell();

        cell.Style.Add("word-wrap", "break-word");
        cell.Attributes.Remove("class");
        cell.Attributes.Remove("rowspan");
        cell.Style.Remove("display");

        tableAppointment.Rows[i].Cells.Add(cell);

        if (i == 0) //Indicating the header row
        {
          cell.Attributes.Add("ID", dr.RoomID.ToString());
          cell.InnerHtml = String.Format(
              "<span id='{0}'>{1}</span>",
              dr.RoomID, dr.Roomname
          );
          tableAppointment.Rows[0].Attributes.Add("class", "csstextheader");
        }
        else
        {

          /***********************************************************************
           * Assumption that this is how you are adding the appointments to the 
           * table, did not see it in your quesiton
           ***********************************************************************/ 
          //i-1 to offset the header row
          cell.InnerHtml = dr.Appointments[i-1].Name;

          //NumberOfTimeSlots does not have to be part of the object, you are already doing it one way (not shown)
          cell.RowSpan = dr.Appointments[i - 1].NumberOfTimeSlots;

          //This is the inportant part, incrementing the row counter for this table by the number of cells you need to be removed becasue of the rowspan.
          //NOTE: I do not like the idea of messing with a loop counter, I would try to refactor your code, but since it was not provided this is a temporary fix.
          i += dr.Appointments[i - 1].NumberOfTimeSlots - 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

public class Room
{
  public int RoomID { get; set; }
  public string Roomname { get; set; }
  public List<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }

  public Room()
  {
    Appointments = new List<Appointment>();
  }
}

public class Appointment
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int NumberOfTimeSlots { get; set; }
}
```

Default.aspx:

Time Slot
        
      
      
        08:00AM00
         15
         30
         40

```
    <tr><td>09:00AM</td><td>00</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>15</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>30</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>40</td></tr>

    <tr><td>10:00AM</td><td>00</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>15</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>30</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>40</td></tr>

    <tr><td>11:00AM</td><td>00</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>15</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>30</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>40</td></tr>

    <tr><td>12:00PM</td><td>00</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>15</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>30</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>40</td></tr>

    <tr><td>01:00PM</td><td>00</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>15</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>30</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>40</td></tr>

    <tr><td>02:00PM</td><td>00</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>15</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>30</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>40</td></tr>

    <tr><td>03:00PM</td><td>00</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>15</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>30</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>40</td></tr>

    <tr><td>04:00PM</td><td>00</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>15</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>30</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>40</td></tr>

    <tr><td>05:00PM</td><td>00</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>15</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>30</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>40</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```