# ASP.NET MVC How to create table structure dynamically in view from viewmodel collection of nested objects

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, view

I am trying to display all the courses for a bunch of user-selected semesters dynamically maintaining the format just like in the EXPECTED screenshot while looping(so that semester shows only once for the respective courses that belong to it, and course name(CourseA) shows only once for the respective sections that belong to that course):

EXPECTED (only for 1 semester currently selected, for more selected semesters same display pattern should be maintained)
[image]

ACTUAL RESULT
[image]

I have a List that is the Model.SemesterSchedule where the data is stored. This is what I tried but its not working, the layout is broken when using the multiple foreach loops, and I am not sure a triple foreach is even a good idea in the first place, please suggest alternate ways that are better:

I have the following structure:

```
class SemesterSchedule
{
   public int SemesterID {get;set;}
   public int SemesterName {get;set;}
   public int TotalClassSections {get;set;}
   public List<Course> Courses {get;set;}
}

class Course
{
   public string CourseTitle {get;set}
   public int ClassID {get;set;}
   public List<ClassSection> Sections {get;set}
}

class ClassSection
{  
   public string SectionType {get;set;}   // Lecture or Lab etc
   public int ClassID {get;set;}
   public string InstructorFirstName {get;set;}
   --------------------------------------
   public bool Monday {get;set;}
   public TimeSpan MondayStart {get;set;}
   public TimeSpan MondayEnd {get;set;}
   ------------------------------------------
}


@if (Model.SemestersSchedule != null && Model.SemestersSchedule.Count() > 0)
{
  <table id="CourseScheduleTable">
     <thead>
          <tr>
             <th>Term</th>
             <th>Course</th>
             <th>Section</th>
             <th>Class#</th>
             <th>Instructor Name</th>
             <th>MON</th>
             <th>TUE</th>
             <th>WED</th>
             <th>THU</th>
             <th>FRI</th>
             <th>SAT</th>
          </tr>
     </thead>
      <tbody>                                                 
      @{
        foreach (SemesterSchedule sc in Model.SemestersSchedule)
        {
             <tr>
               <td rowspan="@sc.TotalSections">@sc.SemesterName</td>
             </tr>

          foreach (Course c in sc.Courses)
          {
           <tr>
             <td rowspan="@c.Sections.Count()">@c.Course.CourseRunTitle</td>
           </tr>

               foreach (ClassSection s in c.Sections)
               {
                 <tr>                                                   
                    <td>@s.SectionType</td>
                    <td>@s.Classroom</td>
                    <td>@c.Course.FirstName @c.Course.MiddleName @c.Course.LastName</td>                                                                 

                    <td>@(s.Monday ? new DateTime(s.MondayStart.Ticks).ToString("HH:mm tt") + "-" + new DateTime(s.MondayEnd.Ticks).ToString("HH:mm tt") : "---")</td>

                    <td>@(s.Tuesday ? new DateTime(s.TuesdayStart.Ticks).ToString("HH:mm tt") + "-" + new DateTime(s.TuesdayEnd.Ticks).ToString("HH:mm tt") : "---")</td>

                    <td>@(s.Wednesday ? new DateTime(s.WednesdayStart.Ticks).ToString("HH:mm tt") + "-" + new DateTime(s.WednesdayEnd.Ticks).ToString("HH:mm tt") : "---")</td>

                    <td>@(s.Thursday ? new DateTime(s.ThursdayStart.Ticks).ToString("HH:mm tt") + "-" + new DateTime(s.ThursdayEnd.Ticks).ToString("HH:mm tt") : "---")</td>

                    <td>@(s.Friday ? new DateTime(s.FridayStart.Ticks).ToString("HH:mm tt") + "-" + new DateTime(s.FridayEnd.Ticks).ToString("HH:mm tt") : "---")</td>

                    <td>@(s.Saturday ? new DateTime(s.SaturdayStart.Ticks).ToString("HH:mm tt") + "-" + new DateTime(s.SaturdayEnd.Ticks).ToString("HH:mm tt") : "---")</td>
               </tr>
             }
          }
       }
   }
</tbody>
```

Comment: please expand on "the layout is broken". what specifically is happening and what specifically are you expecting

Comment: @GregH Done, I added the requested photo denoting what actually happens and clarified the image of what is expected.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a `<td>` with `rowspan="n"` attribute, you must not use another `<td>` for the next n lines.

The correct HTML should be:

```
<table class="blueTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Term</th>
            <th>Course</th>
            <th>Section</th>
            <th>Class</th>
            <th>Instructor</th>
            <th>MON</th>
            <th>TUE</th>
            <th>WED</th>
            <th>THU</th>
            <th>FRI</th>
            <th>SAT</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr> <!-- 11 columns -->
            <td rowspan="4">2019 Term Spring</td>
            <td rowspan="2">CourseA</td>
            <td>Lecture</td>
            <td>219</td>
            <td>John Doe</td>
            <td>---</td>
            <td>09:00</td>
            <td>---</td>
            <td>09:00</td>
            <td>---</td>
            <td>---</td>
        </tr>
        <tr> <!-- 9 columns -->
            <td>Lab</td>
            <td>2019</td>
            <td>John Doe</td>
            <td>---</td>
            <td>11:00</td>
            <td>---</td>
            <td>---</td>
            <td>---</td>
            <td>---</td>
        </tr>
        <tr> <!-- 10 columns -->
            <td>CourseB</td>
            <td>Lecture</td>
            <td>212</td>
            <td>Jennifer Doe</td>
            <td>09:00</td>
            <td>---</td>
            <td>11:00</td>
            <td>---</td>
            <td>---</td>
            <td>---</td>
        </tr>
        <tr> <!-- 10 columns -->
            <td>CourseC</td>
            <td>Lecture</td>
            <td>102</td>
            <td>Jim B</td>
            <td>---</td>
            <td>---</td>
            <td>---</td>
            <td>---</td>
            <td>---</td>
            <td>13:00</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As seen in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8hmyetu5/).

Comment: thanks for that, its just that when using a foreach I cant maintain that format, so how to incorporate that pattern with a foreach and maintain desired display format?

Comment: Maybe this should help: [Generated table with rowspan causing extra cells](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13598263/1109794)